# Strange issue for iCloud Ubiquity Container in Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, macos, icloud

I have distributed my iPad/iPhone universal app "Consumptions" in the store. The app uses iCloud UIDocument to share the database between the devices. Works fine ;-)
Now I want to develop an OS X pendant with access to the same iOS iCloud document. In Xcode/Capabilities I tried to add the Ubiquity Container from the iOS project to the Mac project but I get a red "!" in the Mac project. If I click on "Fix Issue" the "!" disappears on the Mac project but appears on the iOS project.
Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to manually add a "Provision Profile" under "Build Settings / Code Signing" section in Xcode 5 for the iOS and OS X project.