# When Xcode adds the "iCloud" entitlement to my App ID for my iOS project, it invalidates the entitlement for Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, icloud, entitlements

I have a Mac project and an iOS project that both use iCloud capabilities.  When I created the Mac app there was a red "!" next to Add the "iCloud" entitlement to your App iD, in the iCloud section of the Capababilities tab.  When I click "Fix Issue", the red "!" appeared in the corresponding window of the iOS project.

Now whenever I build one app, it undoes whatever "Fix Issue" fixed on the other.

I found the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979732/strange-issue-for-icloud-ubiquity-container-in-xcode-5-0) here on SO but the only suggestion was to manually add a "Provision Profile" under "Build Settings / Code Signing" section in Xcode 5 for the iOS and OS X project.  I experimented with a number of different things but I don't know how to create a Provisioning Profile that will work for both the Mac and iOS builds.  The choices in the iOS project are iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *, and None.  Likewise in the Mac project it's Mac Team Provisioning Profile: *, and None.

In the Apple Member Center.  It seems I can add a profile for Mac or iOS, but not one profile for both.

How can I get Xcode to allow me to compile each application (Mac and iOS) without having to Fix Issue each time I alternate between them?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a single project with two targets (one for iOS, and one for Mac) or are they two different Xcode projects?

Comment: If you're targeting both OS X and iOS, you should be using different provisioning profiles for different platforms. You're not supposed to add one profile for both.

Comment: @Jay Versluis I'm using two different projects.

Comment: @Tom Harrington Apparently Xcode is using two different profiles but it seems like the iOS profile supplants the Mac profile and when I let Xcode fix that, the Mac profile messes up the iOS profile and visa versa.  I'm not doing anything with profiles explicitly, I'm letting Xcode manage them.  If there is a way to explicitly manage the profiles rather than have Xcode fix/break them, I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is absurd but here's what I did before the issue "fixed itself".

I exported my account using Xcode preferences.  I disabled my Mac in the Apple dev Member Center.  I revoked my most recent Mac Development Certificate in member center - there were two that differed only by expiration date.  I changed my Team in the Mac project to None.  I got Xcode to cough up the Xcode quit unexpectedly Problem report even though it didn't quit at all.  This is reproducible by by trying to "Run" the app with team set to None.  I punched "Fix Issue" a couple few times.  I set the Team back to where it was originally, imported the accounts I had previously exported.

Voila.  No more flip-flopping of the iOS/Mac entitlement issue.

Comment: Do we have to create another app ID if we want our existing app to support for iCloud?